# Java. TDD. Как проверить в юнит тесте что исключение было выброшено?

Tags: java, test-driven-development

У меня метод при определенных условиях бросает разные исключения, и я хочу в тесте проверить что он их бросает, и именно те что нужно.

```
} else {
    throw new ImposableMoveException("Error move");
}
```

И так далее...

Подскажите есть ли у junit или еще у какой-то работающей с ней библиотеки, такой метод? И если можно с кратким примером синтаксиса.

Попробовал использовать Rule но что-то идет не так:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void whenThen() throws ImposableMoveException {
    for (int i = 0; i != Board.desc.length; i++) {
        Board.desc[i][i] = new Place(new Cell(i, i), "");
    }
    Board board = new Board();
    Cell cell = new Cell(5, 5);
    board.move(new Cell(0, 0), cell);
    exception.expect(ImposableMoveException.class);
    exception.expectMessage(containsString("Error move"));
}
```

А ошибка теста указывает на 2 строки 
эту:

```
throw new ImposableMoveException("Error move");
```

и эту:

```
board.move(new Cell(0, 0), cell);
```

Ну собственно понятно что первая исключение кидает а вторая его провоцирует, вроде все работать должно подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибаюсь.

**Я что-то не понимаю в идее работы метода expect() и expectMessage()**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) для этого есть подходящий функционал

*1. В аннотации тест-метода описать какое исключение может быть*

```html
    public class Test1 {
     @Test(exected=ArithmeticException.class)
     public void test1(){
     //TODO:
     }
    }
```

*2. Использовать Rule*

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

class MyRule {
    public void method1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        throw new UnsupportedEncodingException();
    }

    public void method2() throws EOFException {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
}

public class Test1 {

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
    public void test1() {

        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }
    @Test
    public void test2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, EOFException {

        boolean a = false;
        MyRule myRule = new MyRule();

        if (a) {
            exception.expect(UnsupportedEncodingException.class);
            myRule.method1();
        } else {
            exception.expect(EOFException.class);
            myRule.method2();
        }
    }
}
```

Подробнее об использовании @Rule можно прочесть [здесь](https://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules).

Comment: Добавлю, что второй вариант предпочтительнее, поскольку позволяет точно указать место, в котором ожидается исключение. При использовании же первого варианта тест может давать ложно-положительный результат: исключение происходит в любом месте теста, тест остается зеленым.

Comment: Попробовал пока что-то не получается ...

Comment: Помогите найти ошибку я код добавил в тему.

Comment: @Павел вам нужно сначала устанавливать ожидания, а потом вызывать метод. У вас сделано наоборот.