# Тест JUnit на исключение, которое должен сгенерировать метод

Tags: java, исключения, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть метод, в котором отлавливается исключение UnsupportedEncodingException. Как правильно написать к нему тест JUnit, который проверяет, отлавливается ли исключение?

```
public static String greeting(String str) {
    try {
        String worldKey = bundle.getString("World");
        String world = new String(worldKey.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        return "Hello, " + world + "!";

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Для таким образом написанного метода никак.

Comment: я бы переписал на `new String(worldKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets. ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`, так исключение `UnsupportedEncodingException` вообще не может быть выброшено.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваш метод не выбрасивает исключение, а возвращает вверх `null`.

Вам надо изменить метод так, чтобы исключение передать вверх.
Например, так:

```
public static String greeting(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        String worldKey = bundle.getString("World");
        String world = new String(worldKey.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        return "Hello, " + world + "!";

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

JUnit можнет ожидать определнное исключение

```
@Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void testPass() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


@Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void testFail() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}


@Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Assert.assertEquals("Hello, World!", greeting("123"));
}
```

Данынй метод имеет ненужный входящий аргумент `str`, который не используется

Другие [примеры](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_exceptions_test.htm) и [документация](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/)

Comment: Спасибо. Если метод пробрасывает исключение, то это исключение должно отлавливаться выше. В моем случае это метод main().

Comment: Проверка исключения путем указания аннотации -- совершенно негибкий инструмент. Если тест или тестируемый код достаточно сложный, то ожидаемое исключение может выпасть совершенно в другом месте, но тест по-прежнему будет зеленым. False positive тесты -- это зло. Лучше пользоваться [`ExpectedException` rule](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595106/106).

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь тестировать реализацию. А нужно тестировать не реализацию, а контракт метода ([пример раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562065/106), [пример два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688124/106)). Контракт метода -- это обещания, как ведет себя метод при разных вариациях входных параметров и при происходящих ошибках.

Контракт метода `greeting()` следующий:

- он возвращает строку "Hello, X!", где X -- некоторая строка, полученная путем преобразования кодировок
- он возвращает `null`, если преобразование кодировок завершилось неудачно

Как видим, в контракте нет ни слова о `UnsupportedEncodingException`. Почему? Потому что это деталь реализации метода.

Соответственно теста у вас должно быть два:

- первый тест проверяет, что при удачной перекодировке возвращается нужная строка
- второй тест проверяет, что при неудачной кодировке возвращается `null`

Т.е. тест должен проверять не факт выпавшего исключения, а то, что метод вернул `null`.

Comment: Спасибо, очень доступно объяснили

Comment: @УильямБлэйк не за что!

Answer (score -1):

Советую использовать [ExpectedException Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Exception-testing), он более гибкий и информативный.
Примеры просты до безобразия.

Comment: Поддерживаю, ExpectedException rule предпочтительнее аннотаций.